# How to reset the Navigation Controller in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

Im working on an App for iOS, thats uses the navigationController to switch betweens views. I'm trying to return from to the root viewcontroller from the third view.
 I have succeeded in the Main.Storyboard, with dragging a button from third to root view, but then the NavigationController just continues the stack.

Is it possible to make a command from third view, to return to root ViewController, without the NavigationController Bar showing the "Back" button and keeping track and without reseting any Bools.

Comment: Hi you should always provide code or screenshots of what you've tried so far. This will help people answer your question better!

Comment: You should spend some time understanding the [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html). Apple has very helpful documentation and [programming guides](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the back button from the navigation bar.Then write the code in third view's viewDidLoad or in viewWillAppear-

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
```

And Now write the code in the body of the action button.Such as-

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Let me know if it works for you.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[UINavigationCobtroller popToRootViewControllerAnimated:]` to close all the view hierarchy to the first but for the remaining issues you can find plenty of answers on SO.